# Python list iteration

Tags: python, list, iteration

So i have a list of heights:

```
heights = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8, 13]
```

And im using this function to store each height integer value and its index in the list in a class i called Node.

```
def initializeNodes(heights):
    ans = []
    for height in heights:
        ans.append(Node(heights.index(height), height))
    return ans
```

But my problem is, because their are two 8's in the list, its giving them both the same first 8 position of 5 in the list:

```
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 5
4 7
5 8
5 8
7 13
```

How can i go around this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to generate an index:

```
def initializeNodes(heights):
    ans = []
    for i, height in enumerate(heights):
        ans.append(Node(i, height))
    return ans
```

You can collapse the four lines into 1 using a list comprehension:

```
def initializeNodes(heights):
    return [Node(i, height) for i, height in enumerate(heights)]
```

Comment: This is perfect and surprisingly a lot simpler than i thought! lol haven't used python in a while and forgot how to use enumerate, silly me

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `list.index` is that it'll only return the index of first occurrence of the item.

```
>>> heights = [1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 5, 7, 8, 8, 13]
>>> heights.index(2)
1
>>> heights.index(5)
4
>>> heights.index(8)
7
```

help on `list.index`:

> L.index(value, [start, [stop]]) -> integer -- return first index of
>   value.

You can do provide a different `start` value to `list.index` than 0, to get the index of repeated items:

```
>>> heights.index(5,heights.index(5)+1) #returns the index of second 5
5
```

But that is very cumbersome, a better solution as @MartijnPieters already mentioned is `enumerate`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're generating the index from the values, why not do it the other way around?

```
heights = [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8, 13]

def initializeNodes(heights):
    ans = []
    for index in range(len(heights)):
        ans.append(Node(index, heights[index]))
    return ans
```

This creates a list from 0 to the length of heights, and then will append the index then the height at this index.

Comment: The enumerate way suggested by @Martijn Pieters is better though, mind.